# Can I start the Mage Guild quest several times?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I haven't finished my Mage's Guild quests in my primary alliance (Aldmeri Dominion) because I knew I'd get a powerful item ranked to my level. I'm at the last quest and so far I refused to go further to get the powerful weapon later in the game rather than now where the game is still rather easy.

Now I'm in my second alliance (Ebonheart Pact) and I have tagged the quest named "Rudrasa's Invitation". That quest is the first quest for the Mage Guild in Stonefalls. While I'm Veteran level 1, the recommended level for that quest is 5 (not veteran level 5: basic level 5).

Am I breaking something here? Is it normal? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not breaking anything. However, you can only do those quests once per character. Even though you'll be able to play through the other alliances, you **won't** be able to complete the main quest line or any of the guild quest lines a second time.

Also don't worry too much about those items. They're levelled to your level, but that scaling is limited (I'm not 100 sure but I think the maximum might be VR5 or something like that?).

A friend of mine tried the same and he didn't get VR14 items on his VR14 character. (This might have changed already though.)

But besides that, if you want to wait, just do so. You won't break anything or miss out on anything, you might just cause different level scaling (in case there are maximum levels).

The recommended levels can be ignored. These quests used to be at fixed levels, but that got changed (which actually made them easier; back at release people had massive problems doing some of the quests, especially the early Mages Guild steps).